# Load AVRO into Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, avro

I have an AVRO file with this schema:

```
{
  "type":"record",
  "name":"row",
  "fields":
  [
    {"name":"Column1","type":"int"},
    {"name":"Column2","type":"string"}
  ]
}
```

Now I'm reading from the staged file.

```
SELECT t.$1
FROM @my_stage/my_file.avro
  ( FILE_FORMAT => 'MY_AVRO' )
  t
;
```

I'm getting this error:

> AVRO file format can produce one and only one column of type variant, object, or array. Load data into separate columns using the MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME copy option or copy with transformation.

I tried to find out what Snowflake sees in this file, using functions like INFER_SCHEMA and METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER, but I always got the same error.

Is it possible to load data from such files?
How should the AVRO schema be changed if not possible? What Snowflake expects from an AVRO file?

I found no clear instructions in the Snowflake documentation.

Resolution:
I was able to load the file when I re-created a stage with a proper table type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce it using provided code sample.

Source file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/_static/examples/episodes.avro

```
CREATE FILE FORMAT MY_AVRO 
    TYPE=AVRO,
    TRIM_SPACE=TRUE,
    REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS=TRUE;

SELECT t.$1
FROM @"TEST"."PUBLIC"."TEST"/episodes.avro(FILE_FORMAT => 'MY_AVRO') AS t;
```

Output:
[image]

---

Infer schema capability works too:

[image]

[image]

---

EDIT:

The error may be caused by misunderstanding how Avro is structured:

```
SELECT t.$1, t.$2
FROM @"TEST"."PUBLIC"."TEST"/episodes.avro(FILE_FORMAT => 'MY_AVRO') AS t;
```

> AVRO file format can produce one and only one column of type variant, object, or array. Load data into separate columns using the MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME copy option or copy with transformation.

There is only single column so there is no `$2` etc.

```
SELECT 
   t.$1:"air_date"::TEXT
  ,t.$1:"doctor"::TEXT
  ,t.$1:"title"::TEXT
  ,METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER
FROM @"TEST"."PUBLIC"."TEST"/episodes.avro(FILE_FORMAT => 'MY_AVRO') AS t;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Lukasz Szozda for such a detailed answer. I tried to load episodes.avro and I've got the same error. What I noted, the file size in staging is 608 bytes, but the file itself has only 597 bytes. I use C# Snowflake.Data to execute a PUT command. I'll try to re-upload the file using a standard tool.

Comment: The difference in size is not relevant. It looks like it is absolutely normal to have this difference. The target file has a different size, no matter what I use, .NET or SnowSQL. The reason for the issue, the stage was created with the default table type, CSV. When I re-created the stage, I could load and view the data OK.